# PHP / RegEx identify multiple patterns on lines

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently building a content parser and I'm stuck with the regex part.

I wrote a pattern that seems to work for every occurence but I'd like to differentiate lines where it appears 1, 2 or 3 times.

Example :

```
Testing text ###img=12545## and content ###big=45124##
Text again

###img=875425## ###big=54634##

Testing text again and again

###medium=6987412## ###big=6542## ###big=6542##
```

My goal is to replace a single pattern with my image tag but when pattern repeats 2 or x times I'd like to wrap it in a special tag like this output :

```
Testing text <img class="img" src="12545"> and content <img class="big" src="45124">
Text again

<div class="two">
<img class="img" src="875425">
<img class="big" src="54634">
</div>

Testing text again and again

<div class="three">
<img class="medium" src="6987412">
<img class="big" src="6542">
<img class="big" src="6542">
</div>
```

The two following regex patterns do identify images, but I can not figure how to make it matching the different repeats : one OR two OR three.

```
$re = "/###([^#]+)##/"; 
$re = "/###(\\w+)=(\\d+)##/i";
```

I'm sure I'd have to write three separate patterns for the 3 cases but how ???

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's probably easier to do two passes: one to replace the tags, and one to wrap them.

Comment: read your string line by line and use `substr_count` to know how many `###` there are in the line and use the correct pattern.

Comment: or use `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 0):

Split your text into lines, then for each line, run a `preg_replace_callback`. You can keep track of the replacement count here and use it later.

```
$txt = '###img=12545## and content ###big=45124##
###img=875425## ###big=54634##
###medium=6987412## ###big=6542## ###big=6542##';

$re = "/###([^#]+)##/"; 

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$txt);

foreach($lines as &$line){
    $count = 0;
    $line = preg_replace_callback(
            $re,
            function ($matches) {
                global $count;
                $count += 1;
                $code = explode('=',$matches[1]);
                return '<img class="' .$code[0]. '" src="' . $code[1]. '">';
            },
            $line
        );
    $line = '<div class="img' .$count. '">' . $line . '</div><br/>';
}
```

Comment: How could this work to replace "line by line" in this case ?